# how to display values stored in multi dimenssional array?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created a multidimensional array.I wants to display it in the .aspx page. please help.my code is here.It doesnt shows the array values

```
    string[,] array_questions = new string[dt.Rows.Count, dt.Columns.Count];

    for (i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
        {
            array_questions[i, j] = dt.Rows[i][j].ToString();

            //TextBox1.Text = array_questions[i,j];
        }
    } 
    Console.Write(array_questions[i, j] + " ");
```

Comment: Are you writing this in an event handler such as Load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also use Response.write

Comment: why write a similar response to mine? ^ ^

Comment: your respone and my response didn't have a minute diff  ? I haven't seen yours you can see that

Answer (score 1):

`Console.Write` is used for console applications.
If you want to display the data on the aspx webpage you need to create a webcontrol (for example label) and set its text property with an appropriate value.

Comment: the op is asking exactly how to do this, show some example code would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write the values ​​in the table in the console visual studio, call the method

`Console.Out.Write()` and not `Console.Write()`.
Otherwise call `Response.Write()` to write on the page

Answer (score 0):

```
        // display the array

        for (int i = 0; i < array_questions.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < array_questions.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                Response.Write("i="+i+"   "+"j="+j);
                Response.Write("<br>");

            }
        }
```